# Rim size for 215/55/R17 tire

Tags: tires, wheels

I had a minor accident today and my Toyota Camry 2007 SE had both of it's right side tires flat. I changed the front tire because it was slashed. My back tire is still intact, but the rim is bent and I need a new one. I want to use my 215/55/17 tire on it but I do not what size rim to get. Every website I go to show up rims that are 16.5-19 size. I am not really strong at auto maintenance, I am trying to make sure I get the right rims.
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are you just trying to replace the stock rim? This is highly what I'd suggest you do. I'm not sure what the standard size of the rim is, but if you look at the backside of the rim (the part which faces the brakes), it's usually stamped there in small-ish letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is [understating tire sizes](https://pepboys.com/tires/treadsmart/understanding_tire_markings).

With that said I *think* you're looking for a tire that is 17 x ~8. To be doubly certain you can cheat a little and call a shop and say that you need to replace a wheel, give them your car's year/make/model and the size of your tire (215/55/17) and ask what wheel you need and what it would cost. Then match that against an online order.

I'm not too familiar with tire/wheel match either so take my 17x8 estimate with a grain of salt.

---

Additionally your damaged wheel should have its data written on it. You need to math based off that or factory spec. As Paulster2 mentioned, bolt pattern (of course) and offset are other factors as well. And these can't be guessed at by the tire spec.

The best advice I can give you, match to your other wheel on the rear axle or go to a shop.

### IMPORTANT

If the tire & wheel you're trying to install is not a match to your 3 other wheels - don't install it.

Comment: You are probably very close to right with the 8, but it may be smaller. The real thing at issue here is to ensure the new wheel has the correct offset, as well as being the correct width and diameter. Then you also have to have the lug pattern/size.